# How to manage connections of neurons inside ANN using OpenCV::ML?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, neural-network, perceptron

So there is [grate sample](http://projectagv.blogspot.com/2008/12/sample-code-for-cvannmlp.html) (only one real sample we found). And it is quite limiting. It shows how to create an architecture of artificial neutral network where all neurons of one layer are connected (forward) to all neurons of following (next) layer. We want to manage this connections so to create a ANN where each neuron of second layer is only connected to 2 neurons of next layer.   so we want:

```
           Layer 1: 2 neurons (2 inputs)
           Layer 2: 3 neurons (hidden layer) (each neuron is connected to 2 neurons of next Layer (3) )
           Layer 3: 3 neurons (hidden layer)
           Layer 4: 1 neurons (1 output)
```

Comment: Not sure how to do this with OpenCV, but I've used [this](http://www.philbrierley.com/code.html) back-prop network extensively, and I think it may do what you want.

Comment: [This](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/neural_networks.html) may be useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can initialize the we weight for the connection you dont want to zero and make the learning rate for those weights to zero.